# Multisig created from Multisig address

Tags: p2sh, multi-signature

Can a multisig address creation process use other multisig addresses as signers to result in a new multisig address

Would this also result in a greater number of signers to be necessary to approve a result/transaction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  A "multisig address" is really a hash of a redeem script encoded as a P2SH address.  Redeem scripts can't be nested, which means you can't include one redeem script inside another redeem script, so it is impossible to implement the feature you describe under current Bitcoin consensus rules.